# In app navigation in react native app using mapbox

Tags: react-native, mapbox

is there any wat to show in app navigation in react native

I found this https://medium.com/alameda-dev/installing-react-native-mapbox-navigation-in-ios-e35d43c5987a but what is solution for android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package and the documentation it is a Turn by turn navigation https://reactnativeexample.com/smart-mapbox-turn-by-turn-routing-based-on-real-time-traffic-for-react-native/

Answer (score 0):

Bro this library is Perfectly fine for Both platform

```
https://github.com/homeeondemand/react-native-mapbox-navigation#readme
```

or you can install from  my repo e.g

```
npm install @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation@https://github.com/mirzahayat/react-native-mapbox-navigation.git
```

or

```
yarn add @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation@https://github.com/mirzahayat/react-native-mapbox-navigation.git
```

for further guidance you can follow the library

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly then the best way to create navigation in react native is use dedicated library: https://reactnavigation.org/